# Regex for certain characters in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract certain characters from text and I have encountered some special characters in these texts and I'm not sure whether they are emojis or something else. I need to extract those special characters from the sentence and needed some kind of regex for it.This is the sentence along with the special characters-

'technews One lone dude awaits iPad 2 at Apple\x89Ûªs SXSW store'

Comment: Go through this - https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can do reverse way to only extra if character or digit.:

Option 1:

```py
import re
ini_string = "'technews One lone dude awaits iPad 2 at Apple\x89Ûªs SXSW store"
res1 = " ".join(re.split("[^A-Za-z0-9]+", ini_string)) 
print(res1)
```

option 2:

```py
result2 = ini_string.encode().decode("utf-8").replace(u"\x89Ûª", "`").encode("utf-8")
```

Option 3:

```py
new_string = ini_string.encode('ascii',errors='ignore')
print(new_string)
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any way to extract only these special characters?

Comment: you want to get that character or remove it from string and return actual string ?

Comment: I want to extract the special characters and store them seperately.